# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading id) at HTMLButtonElement.btn.onclick

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, axios

I am trying to access the `._id` here.
so I have an event listener as a main, then in that, I am calling the response from Axios as the .get method.
In the promise exception which is `.then`, I equal the `dataUsers = response.data` which will give me all the Users in the database if I log it out.
I have an if and else, and when else executes it has a for loop, it will loop out all the users and will display in the table.
so I have an edit and delete button which will also display over the looping and will be available to each user, that they can edit or delete it if they want, so in order to do that I have created a
onclick/addeventlistener inside the for loop and in onclick/eventlistener function I am passing a function that is defined outside the main eventlistener.
My problem is If I pass the parameter dataUsers[i]._id  (_id is an id which will be in response )  in the function inside the onclick function, It is giving me the **error I wrote in the title** that it _id is undefined.

**but**

this error is solved when I created a let variable inside a for loop which is equal to `dataUsers[i]` and if I pass the `variable._id` in the parameter of the function which is inside the `onclick` function I am getting my answer.

**Can someone explain to me how this is happening and why?
thanks a 1000**

My code is below :

```
BtnAllusers.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("tbod").textContent = ""
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:3000/users")
    .then((response) => {
      dataUsers = response.data;
      console.log(dataUsers);
       if (dataUsers.length === 0) {
        alert("Please Create a User first!!");
      } else {
        for (i = 0; i < dataUsers.length; i++) {


          //let iddata = dataUsers[i]
          //console.log(iddata);

          //console.log(dataUsers[i]._id);


          let trUsers = document.createElement("tr");
          let td1 = document.createElement("td");
          let td2 = document.createElement("td");
          let td3 = document.createElement("td");

 
          var btn1edit = document.createElement('button')
          btn1edit.textContent = "EDIT"
          //btn1edit.addEventListener('click', function() { EDIT(iddata._id) })

          var btn2delete = document.createElement('button')
          btn2delete.textContent = "DELETE"
          btn2delete.onclick = () => { DELETE(dataUsers[i]._id) }  //? Please Explain this line error.
          //btn2delete.onclick = function () { DELETE(iddata._id) }

          let td4 = document.createElement("td")
          let td5 = document.createElement("td")


          td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dataUsers[i].name));
          td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dataUsers[i].email));
          td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dataUsers[i].address));
          td4.appendChild(btn1edit)
          td5.appendChild(btn2delete)


          trUsers.appendChild(td1);
          trUsers.appendChild(td2);
          trUsers.appendChild(td3);
          trUsers.appendChild(td4);
          trUsers.appendChild(td5);
          document.getElementById("tbod").appendChild(trUsers);
          //console.log(dataUsers[i]._id);
        }

      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```